# Text align NEXT to the Img - wordpress text editor

Tags: wordpress

Can you help me to align text next to the image without floating under the image in the WordPress text editor? Tried float left img and float right text, overflow:hidden etc. no effect in the text editor.

Here is how its now:
https://ctrlv.cz/KGG0

And I need to do this:
https://ctrlv.cz/KQ1k

Thank you for help.

Comment: It appears you linked the same image twice. Could you update the links so I can get a clearer picture of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot achieve this by just using `float` on the image as it will make the text to wrap under the image when there is space available. You can do this in two ways:

1. Using tables: If you're using the old WordPress text editor, you can create a table from the editor's toolbar. Create a table with one row and two columns. Add the image to the left column and the text into the second column.
2. If you're using the Gutenberg editor, you can use the Columns layout element and add content into the left and right column. [Info on how to use the Gutenberg Column block](https://www.pair.com/support/kb/gutenberg-editor-how-to-use-columns/)

If you're familiar with HTML, you can also do this with some simple code:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">Image column</div>
  <div class="column">Text column</div>
</div>
```

and style the `row` and `column` as required.

Comment: Table looks good on pc but on resposible view (iphone) image is still next to the text (still the table) and very small. Any other solution, how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: Tables are not responsive by default. Using the Columns element in the Gutenberg editor is the better option. If you aren't using the Gutenberg editor, then use the HTML mentioned. You will need additional CSS to make the HTML responsive. See this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/veesar/pen/dyRvOBZ?editors=1100)